# How to Pop up WPF form through PowerShell Background job?

Tags: wpf, powershell, powershell-5.0

I am looking an option to pop up WPF form through PowerShell background job.

I tried different method, but failed. So, seeking your help.

I could pop up normal windows form, but the challenges comes when I am deciding to use WPF. Code is working fine without background job.

Here is my complete PowerShell code which will run in background. Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Below code is saved in a file "BackgroundJob.ps1". And this file being called from Show-Popups function mentioned below.

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param($TaskName,$ScriptPath)

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')



[xml]$xaml =@"
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFScrollViewerSample" 
Name="window" WindowStyle="None" Height="250" Width="500"
ResizeMode="noresize" ShowInTaskbar="False" WindowStartupLocation="Manual"  
    >

<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
        
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                <Border Background="#313130">
                    <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
    </Style>


</Window.Resources>
          
    <Grid Name="grid" Background="#313130" Height="250" Width="500">


        <Label Name="Label" Content="" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" Margin="70,100,0,0"/>


        

        <Button Name="Dismiss" Content="Dismiss" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="250,170,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Height="24" Background="Gray" Foreground="White"/>
        <Button Name="Yes" Content="Yes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,170,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Height="24" Background="Gray" Foreground="White"/>

    </Grid>


</Window>
"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
try{$Pop_op=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader."; break}
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Pop_op.FindName($_.Name)}

#Yes Button Event
$Yes.add_click({
       #Import data in DB
        #Export Runtime Logs
        if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Error)){
                $Error  | Out-File -FilePath "$env:temp\RuntimeError.log"  -Force -Append 
            }
        $Error.Clear()
        #Close Form
        $Pop_op.Close()            
                        
})
#Dismiss Button Event
$Dismiss.add_click({
        $Pop_op.Close()
})



$Pop_op.Left = $([System.Windows.SystemParameters]::WorkArea.Width-$Pop_op.Width)
$Pop_op.Top = $([System.Windows.SystemParameters]::WorkArea.Height-$Pop_op.Height)
$Label.Content ='Do you wants to perform '+$TaskName + '?'


#$Pop_op.Show();$Pop_op.Activate()
$Pop_op.ShowDialog() #| Out-Null
if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Error)){
                $Error  | Out-File -FilePath "$env:temp\RuntimeError.log"  -Force -Append 
            }
```

Here is the code to create background job

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {   
    Import-Module "C:\Data\MyFunctions.ps1" -Force
    Show-Popups -ScriptPath 'C:\Data'
  
}
```

Show-Popups - is the function to call Powershell background job script "BackgroundJob.ps1".

Comment: [1] what version of PoSh do you want to work with? generally, you otta use the lowest one that you need to work with - not 3 different versions. unless, of course, your code needs to be written in 3 different versions ... [*grin*] ///// [2] my understanding is that background stuff runs in a non-interactive session. if that is correct, then you can't do what you want via a _background_ job or runspace.

Comment: I am using PowerShell version 5.1.17134.858

Comment: please REMOVE the v2.0, v3.0, and v4.0 tags from your Question. they will cause confusion - and may cause folks to bypass your post since v2 is not available to most people anymore.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have added the correct tags.

Comment: you are welcome! [*grin*] ///// every article i have found seems to _imply_ that background jobs are NOT able to use any user interaction. however, none of them _say it specifically_ ... and i am not good enuf to determine the facts. hopefully some kind guru will drop by an enlighten both of us ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this through some workaround method.

Solution:

1. Create a VB script, and run PS script through it.
2. Call the VBs using Wscript.exe

VBs Code:

```
command = "PowerShell.exe -executionpolicy Bypass -file C:\script.ps1"

set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

shell.Run command,0
```